# convert date format from "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" to "dd MMM yyyy" in swift

Tags: date, datetime, swift3, nsdate, dateformatter

I tried to convert from 11/17/2017 to 17 Nov 2017 but got this date 17 jan 2017.
Here is the code that i have try.

```
func convertDateFormater(_ date: String) -> String
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

}
print(convertDateFormater("11/17/2017 12:24:41 PM"))
```

Output : - 17 jan 2017

Can anyone help me where i'm doing mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use uppercase `M` to get the month.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
```

Also... fix your variable names.